# How to change color of the active/inactive window?

Tags: 17.10

Is there a way for me to change the color of the active window (titlebar and such) because quite frankly the default "inactive" and "active" differentiation between them is very subtle that I have no idea which window is currently active and I often find myself typing away only to find a little while that it was in a wrong window.

I'm using GNOME if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you've asked for, but nevertheless to distinguish between focussed and background windows you may use blur effect for background windows. To achieve that you may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Windows Blur Effects](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/891/windows-blur-effects/). You can change the desaturation, brightness and contrast of background windows using this extension.

[image]
 (screenshot source: extension's homepage at extensions.gnome.org)

Comment: Thanks for the tip although this is a little too much than what I'm asking for. I have a dual screen and I'd still want to be able to read from inactive window (even though I can lower the settings). A simple title color change would be ideal scenario in my case.